# Accumulate based on lagged values and values in different columns in R

Tags: r, purrr, accumulate

I have the following dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(fractile = 1:10) %>% mutate(bracketaverage = fractile*100, topaverage = 10:19)
```

Which looks like:

```
 fractile bracketaverage topaverage
1         1            100         10
2         2            200         11
3         3            300         12
4         4            400         13
5         5            500         14
6         6            600         15
7         7            700         16
8         8            800         17
9         9            900         18
10       10           1000         19
```

I wish to modify the topaverage column by utilizing input from the remaining columns according to the specified formula:

```
topaverage = ( (100-lag(fractile) ) * lag(topaverage) + ( lag(fractile) - fractile ) * bracket_average ) / (100-fractile)
```

Hence, the formula calculates the topaverage recursively, meaning that each iteration relies on the topaverage from the preceding step.

Comment: I gave a tried with a for loop. I am not sure if your formula is right or if I understood right since I am surprised by the result: 
`c(NA, 8.06122448979592, 5.05154639175258, 0.9375, -4.31578947368421, 
-10.7446808510638, -18.3870967741935, -27.2826086956522, -37.4725274725275, 
-49)`  
A numeric exemple of the second line (using some data of the first line) :
`( 99 * 10 +  ( 1-2 ) * 200) / (98)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While many of `purrr`'s functions have `func2`-versions for two arguments, two factors make it not easy to use them here: you need *three* variables, and you need both the lag and current version of at least one of them. Because of that, I think we can `purrr::accumulate` over the row indices themselves.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr) # accumulate
df |>
  mutate(
    val = accumulate(
      row_number(), .init = first(topaverage),
      .f = function(ta, i) if (i == 1) ta else {
        ( (100 - fractile[i-1]) * topaverage[i-1] +
            (fractile[i-1] - fractile[i]) * bracketaverage[i] ) /
          (100 - fractile[i])
      })[-1]
  )
#    fractile bracketaverage topaverage       val
# 1         1            100         10 10.000000
# 2         2            200         11  8.061224
# 3         3            300         12  8.020619
# 4         4            400         13  7.958333
# 5         5            500         14  7.873684
# 6         6            600         15  7.765957
# 7         7            700         16  7.634409
# 8         8            800         17  7.478261
# 9         9            900         18  7.296703
# 10       10           1000         19  7.088889
```

where `fractile[i-1]` is giving us `lag(fractile)` and `fractile[i]` is giving us the current-row `fractile`.

I assume that the first `topaverage` is retained unmodified. If that is not true, then this might need adjusting to account for aligning in the other direction (`[i]` and `[i+1]` instead, updating the leading conditional).